# select based on row combinations on different columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame.

```
ID  col1 col2    value
1    4    New     20
2    4    OLD     30
3    5    OLD     60
4    5    New     50
5    3    New     70
```

I would like to select only rows which has the following rules. from `col1` value 4 and 3 should be in `New` and 5 should be in `Old` in `col2`. Drop other rows other wise.

```
ID  col1 col2    value
1    4    New     20
3    5    Old     60
5    3    New     70
```

Can any one help with this in Python pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with filter by `in` chained by `&` for bitwise `AND` and second condition chain by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df1 = df.query("(col1 in [4,3] & col2 == 'New') | (col1 == 5 & col2 == 'OLD')")
print (df1)
   ID  col1 col2  value
0   1     4  New     20
2   3     5  OLD     60
4   5     3  New     70
```

Or use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1 = df[df['col1'].isin([3,4]) & df['col2'].eq('New') | 
         df['col1'].eq(5) & df['col2'].eq('OLD')]
```